# ASP.NET MVC3 Razor Entity Framework - DataFormatString property not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, entity-framework-4.1, jquery-ui-datepicker

When i try to create or save a date in the model the validation trows invalid date format instead of respect my format specified in DataFormatString (dd/MM/yyyy). I saw that the framework try to save the date only in MM/dd/yyyy format. I want to input/output it in dd/MM/yyyy.

I have the following model:

```
public class MyModel {

        public int MyModelID { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime BornDate { get; set; }
}
```

I have the edit template to display data edited:

```
@model DateTime?
@Html.TextBox("", Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), new { @class = "date" })
```

I have a jquery date picker registered with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.date').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
    });
});
```

I have the following view with:

```
<div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataNascimento)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataNascimento)
</div>
```

I have checked ContosoUniversity tutorial and it happens to.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the better options to solve this, is writing you own **ModelBinder** to handle localization, read more about that [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/archive/2008/11/21/mvc-modelbinder-and-localization.aspx)

The attribute `DisplayFormat` is specifies only how *BornDate* field is displayed (and formatted upon displaying), when using `@Html.EditorFor` for instance.

Comment: This solution works but the example in the link is deprecated because IModelBinder interface have now another signature.

Comment: Another possible solution consists to change in Region and Language the formats of date and time.